# Set variable depending of conditional

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple variable assignation with case clause like:

```
DECLARE @CurrentType INT

SELECT
     @CurrentType = (CASE
                     WHEN [CL].[ProjectKey] IS NOT NULL
                     THEN 0
                     ELSE 1
                  END)
     FROM [Project] AS [P]
         LEFT JOIN [CallLog] AS [CL] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [CL].[ProjectKey]


SELECT
     @CurrentType
```

But it always return NULL instead 1 or 0

I also try using `IIF` conditional like:

```
DECLARE @CurrentType INT = (SELECT 
                            IIF([CL].[ProjectKey] IS NOT NULL , 1 , 0)
                            FROM [Project] AS [P]
                                LEFT JOIN [CallLog] AS [CL] ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [CL].[ProjectKey] )

                                SELECT
                 @CurrentType
```

But same history, how can I get desire result? which is 1 or 0? Regards

Comment: Look at the ISNULL function ...it will give you a default instead of null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression:

```
SELECT @CurrentType = (CASE WHEN [CL].[ProjectKey] IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM [Project] [P] LEFT JOIN
     [CallLog] [CL]
      ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [CL].[ProjectKey];
```

Could only set `@CurrentType` to `NULL` if the query returned no rows.  Given that you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, this would imply that `Project` is empty.

If you change this to an aggregation query, you will also get one row, so this might do what you want:

```
SELECT @CurrentType = (CASE WHEN MAX([CL].[ProjectKey]) IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM [Project] [P] LEFT JOIN
     [CallLog] [CL]
      ON [P].[ProjectKey] = [CL].[ProjectKey];
```

Comment: I try it but still getting null value

Comment: but you give me an idea, and I do `(CASE
         WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END)` and it works! thanks, Note: I don't know if this is a workaround but works in my case

Comment: @Leon . . . I meant something similar, but I put the `MAX()` int he wrong place.